# How to enable Scrollview in a Component Within a Component

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

[Screenshot Of View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NjR4.png)

I am trying to add Scrollview in my main screen where i am showing an array of products. As I add a SCROLLVIEW on my screen it does not enable the scroll feature. I have made a View where a  component is being rendered each of which having a array of its own.

The Code

**Newsfeed.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import Connections from './Components/Connections';
import ClearStock from './Components/ClearStock';
import NewProducts from './Components/NewProducts';
import Discounts from './Components/Discounts';
import CustomButton from './Components/CustomButton';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

// import {ScrollView} from 'react-native';

export default class NewsFeed extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: 'ClearStock',
  };
  buttonClick(name) {
    this.setState({selected: name});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',borderWidth:5,backgroundColor:'#ffc687'}}>


          <CustomButton
            style={styles.btnStyle}
            onPress={() => this.buttonClick('ClearStock')}
            iconName="stumbleupon-circle">
           Clear Stock
          </CustomButton>

          <CustomButton
              style={styles.btnStyle}         
            onPress={() => this.buttonClick('Discounts')}
            iconName="home" >
            Discounts
          </CustomButton>

          <CustomButton
             style={styles.btnStyle}         
            onPress={() => this.buttonClick('NewProducts')}
            iconName="free-code-camp">
            New Products
          </CustomButton>

          <CustomButton
             style={styles.btnStyle}           
            onPress={() => this.buttonClick('Connections')}
            iconName="home">
            Connections
          </CustomButton>

        </View>

        <View>
          {this.state.selected === 'ClearStock' ? (
            <ClearStock />
          ) : this.state.selected === 'Discounts' ? (
            <Discounts />
          ) : this.state.selected === 'NewProducts' ? (
            <NewProducts />
          ) : (
            <Connections />
          )}
       </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
styles=StyleSheet.create({
  btnStyle:{
    marginLeft:40,
    // backgroundColor:'red',
    borderRadius:10,

  }
});
```

**CustomCard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {ImageBackground, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';


export default class CustomCard extends Component {

    state = {
        product: [

            {
                name: "Mug",
                quantity: 2,
                price: 199,
                category: "Kitchen ware",
                tags: ["mug", "kitchen", "utensils"],
                color: "White",
                imageUrl: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61KB6fUhcSL._SL1500_.jpg"

            },
            {
                name: "Samsung A50",
                quantity: 6,
                price: 15000,
                category: "Mobile Phone",
                tags: ["mug", "kitchen", "phone"],
                color: "Black",
                imageUrl: "https://johnlewis.scene7.com/is/image/JohnLewis/238087827?$rsp-pdp-port-1440$"

            },
            {
                name: "Nokia A50",
                quantity: 6,
                price: 15000,
                category: "Mobile Phone",
                tags: ["mug", "kitchen", "phone"],
                color: "Black",
                imageUrl: "https://assets.mspimages.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Nokia-X71-696x435.jpg"

            },
            {
                name: "QMobile A50",
                quantity: 6,
                price: 15000,
                category: "Mobile Phone",
                tags: ["mug", "kitchen", "phone"],
                color: "Black",
                imageUrl: "https://www.whatmobile.com.pk/admin/images/Qmobile/NoirJ5b.jpg"

            },

        ]

    }
    render() {

        const { name, quantity, price, category, tags, color, imageUrl } = this.props.products;

        return (
            <View >
                <ImageBackground
                    style={styles.productView}
                    source={{ uri: "https://www.akfoconee.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/kids-martial-arts-landing-page-section-two-background-min-min.png" }}
                >

                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <Icon name="bullhorn" size={30} />
                        <View style={{ marginLeft: 30, padding: 10, height: "100%", borderRadius: 30, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "orange", width: "30%" }}>
                            <Image style={{ marginLeft: 10, height: "100%", width: 100, resizeMode: "contain" }} source={{ uri: imageUrl }} />


                        </View>

                        <View style={{ padding: 1, marginLeft: 10 }}>


                            <Text> We are offering FLASH SALE</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.itemDescription}>{name}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.itemDescription}>{quantity}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.itemDescription}> original price RS {price}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.itemDescription}> price for 100 products RS {price}</Text>

                        </View>



                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>

        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    itemDescription: {
        fontSize: 15,
        color: "black",
    },
    productView: {
        // borderRadius:30,
        // backgroundColor:"red",
        elevation: 2,
        paddingTop: 15,
        paddingBottom: 15,
        paddingLeft: 15,
        paddingRight: 15,
        height: 150,
        width: "100%",
        marginLeft: 15,
        // marginRight: 20,
        marginTop: 10,
        // borderWidth: 0.14,
        // borderRadius:10
        // marginBottom:50,
        // borderColor:"black"
    }
})
```

**ClearStock.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import CustomCard from './CustomCard';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
export default class ClearStock extends Component {
  state = {
    product: [

        {
            name: "Mug",
            quantity: 2,
            price: 199,
            category: "Kitchen ware",
            tags: ["mug", "kitchen", "utensils"],
            color: "White",
            imageUrl: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61KB6fUhcSL._SL1500_.jpg"

        },
        {
            name: "Samsung A50",
            quantity: 6,
            price: 15000,
            category: "Mobile Phone",
            tags: ["mug", "kitchen", "phone"],
            color: "Black",
            imageUrl: "https://johnlewis.scene7.com/is/image/JohnLewis/238087827?$rsp-pdp-port-1440$"

        },
        {
            name: "Nokia A50",
            quantity: 6,
            price: 15000,
            category: "Mobile Phone",
            tags: ["mug", "kitchen", "phone"],
            color: "Black",
            imageUrl: "https://assets.mspimages.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Nokia-X71-696x435.jpg"

        },
        {
            name: "QMobile A50",
            quantity: 6,
            price: 15000,
            category: "Mobile Phone",
            tags: ["mug", "kitchen", "phone"],
            color: "Black",
            imageUrl: "https://www.whatmobile.com.pk/admin/images/Qmobile/NoirJ5b.jpg"

        },

    ]

}
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>About Clearing Stock</Text>
           {
              this.state.product.map((data,index) => {
                return( 
                  <CustomCard products={data} key={index}></CustomCard>
                    // <Text>Hello</Text>
                  )
              })
            }


      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a flex problem in your application

```
<View style={{width:"100%",flex:1}}>
    <Text>About Clearing Stock</Text>
       {
          this.state.product.map((data,index) => {
            return( 
              <CustomCard products={data} key={index}></CustomCard>
                // <Text>Hello</Text>
              )
          })
        }


  </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have imported the scrollview, but you don't use it anywhere. You should have it as the inner view in your ClearStock component. Remember also scrollview's children should have flex: 1 so make sure your custom card component has flex: 1 in its styling. Try these suggestions out and comment on the result.

Comment: I added Flex:1 in CustomCard's styles.productview

Comment: You are importing the ScrollView but not using it anywhere `<View>
        <Text>About Clearing Stock</Text>
           {
              this.state.product.map((data,index) => {
                return( 
                  <CustomCard products={data} key={index}></CustomCard>
                    // <Text>Hello</Text>
                  )
              })
            }


      </View>` This should be ScrollView not View in ClearStock.js

Comment: Also take a look at FlatList: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist as it might suite your needs better. :)

Comment: Also try adding property `contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}` to the ScrollView itself.